# Were the cave drawings in the mine at Dragonstone authentic?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Season 7 Episode 4 titled *The Spoils of War*,

> Jon Snow shows Daenerys cave drawings made inside the mine at [Dragonstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spoils_of_War_(Game_of_Thrones)):
>
>  Jon shows Daenerys the mine of Dragonglass. Venturing further into the
>  caves, he shows her carvings made on the cave wall by the Children of
>  the Forest, depicting the Children and the First Men fighting together
>  against the White Walkers. Seemingly convinced that Jon is telling the
>  truth, Daenerys vows to fight for the North, but only if Jon bends the
>  knee.

The cave drawings appear to be vivid and bright without much fading.

[image]

[image]

**Were the cave drawings actually drawn by the Children of the Forest?  Is there any evidence that Jon Snow drew them himself to convince Daenerys to fight the White Walkers with him?**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### It's *highly unlikely* Jon Snow painted these and lied about it:

- Jon Snow would somehow have had to brush up on ancient and mystical
  knowledge on the Children of the Forest's **symbology** in order to
  make these seemingly accurate drawings.

  These symbols you see bear significance in the culture of the
  Children of the Forest, which in turn is reflected in the White
  Walkers (which are created by the Children of the Forest)

  [image] <sup>The spiral cave painting
  here on the left coincides with the same geometric pattern that the
  White Walkers put together using corpses in Season 3.</sup>
  [image]
   <sup>Another spiral
  pattern, here seen in a top-down view of one of an elaborate monument
  made by the Children of the Forest, where we have Stonehenge-style
  standing stones in a spiral pattern, seen in S06E05. The creators of the show talk about this pattern in this scene on ['Game of Thrones Season 6: Inside the Episode #5'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9Jsj9V_Aqg)</sup>
  [image] <sup>Here we have what looks
  like the Greek symbol, [phi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi) ('**Φ**'), on the left coinciding
  with the same geometric pattern of corpses that the three rangers in
  S01E01 run into, also put together by White Walkers.</sup>

  The only Westerosi people who might know this much about the White Walkers, Children of the Forest and their symbology are Sam Tarly, Bran Stark (Three-eyed Raven) and perhaps some members of the Reed family. Neither Jon Snow nor Davos would know these things. **While the Night's Watch and the Wildlings [are aware of these symbols](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-5329963ade55424d9c88b35f076d31f0.webp) made by the White Walkers, they wouldn't make the connection with the Children of the Forest, so for Jon Snow to paint these symbols and attribute them so confidently to the Children, while being very accurate, seems extremely far-fetched.**

  This whole idea of Jon Snow faking the cave paintings is essentially debunked, implicitly, by the creators of the show in '[Game of Thrones: Season 7 Episode 4: Inside the Episode (HBO)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X17pjukf8rA)', where D&D discuss the importance of the symbols in the cave and how it relates to the Children of the Forest and the White Walkers.
- Jon Snow would have to have had **blue paint** on-hand

  [image]
   <sup>Close-up of the cave
  painting of the Night King and his White Walker lackeys. The blue in
  their eyes stands out as quite intense and vivid.</sup>

  Blue is [historically the most difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue#In_the_ancient_world) colour to make pigments
  and dyes and paints of, in our world.

  **If we assume the fan-theory to be true, then we also have to assume Jon
  Snow brought blue paint with him to Dragonstone**, just in case he
  needed to draw some White Walkers in a cave, just in case Dany didn't
  believe him. It's not impossible, but not very believable.

  Incidentally, on the topic of **blue**, I found this quote on
  Wikipedia:

  > Reds, blacks, browns, and ochres are found in cave paintings from the Upper Paleolithic period, but not blue.
  >  <sub>—*[Blue (In the
  >   ancient world)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue#In_the_ancient_world)*, Wikipedia</sub>

  It's an interesting, funny fact that would coincidentally lend
  credence to the fan-theory, but one shouldn't compare non-fictional,
  early Homo Sapiens from the Upper Paleolithic era with fantastical,
  magical, spell-casting Children of the Forest in a fictional setting,
  in order to arrive at conclusions about the availability of pigments
  for cave paintings.
- Jon Snow would have to be a skilled liar

  Jon is honourable and true (not a trickster or liar), much like his
  surrogate father, Ned Stark.

  The last time Jon specifically lied was when he had to deceive the
  wildlings into believing he was a turncoat crow - [he even killed
  Qhorin Halfhand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcEL9CARIQA) to sell this deception.

  The thing is, he was already sexually attracted to Ygritte and was
  starting to have conflicting feelings about the wildlings, and the
  pointless violence between them and the Night's Watch, and he was
  starting to see that what he was told about the wildlings wasn't
  true, after spending some days with Ygritte. Had he not had these
  conflicting feelings, he would have executed her when he had the
  chance. All this to say: he didn't really lie, so much as he was
  following Qhorin's orders, and leaning into his true, new, growing
  feelings about the wildlings.

  **It would be very unlike Jon Snow to lie** to Daenerys about this, not to mention **the risk of getting caught lying**, whether because he
  was spotted by guards carrying paint around, or spotted in the middle
  of painting, etc. would jeopardize the entire mission (the *most important* mission in the world) of getting help for the War for the Dawn - a very high risk.

This is one of those fan-theories where it sounds funny/entertaining at first glance, but the more you think about it, the more unlikely it sounds.

Comment: `so for Jon Snow to paint these symbols and attribute them so confidently to the Children, while being very accurate, seems extremely far-fetched.` at the same time if he didn't paint them he *still* needs confidence in his Children of the Forest lore to even broach the subject with Daenerys.

Comment: @Brad Did you [watch the episode](https://youtu.be/LJnMJc6Xgs0?t=2m56s)? I'm glad you bring it up, though, because this way it can exist in the comments, rather than my answer (I had a feeling someone would bring this up)

Comment: I'm not following your response. I'm certainly not suggesting Jon created nay of the paintings.

Comment: @Brad That's fair enough, I'll add detail: The hyperlinked `watch the episode` in my previous comments will send you to a timestamped Youtube video in which Jon and Dany are gazing at a depiction of the First Men and the Children of the Forest. It's from this depiction of the Children (short, little dudes) that Jon (or more likely Davos, who was there with Stannis for a long time, and likely got a few tours, including the cave, as well as any history (as shown in Davos' response "So they did" in [this episode](https://youtu.be/iM9yWiML7fM?t=36s)) concluded the Children drew it.

Comment: One of the best answers i have ever read on here, both in terms of presentation and the quality of the content. I love this website the standards are among the best I have ever come across in social media xx

Comment: @Brad: Jon is biased. He can jump to the conclusion of the inscriptions being made by the children of the forest because it supports his claim that the white walkers are real. His intention is evidenced by him **blatantly** saying that "the children and the first men worked together despite their mistrust and differences" and immediately following up with "so should we". He is editorialising what the images show (where does it show mistrust?) Jon was trying to convince Dany, he wasn't necessarily interested in the archeological and historical correctness of the origins of the inscriptions.

Answer (score 10):

I know you are not the only one thinking like this and it's all over the internet:

['Game of Thrones' fans are all making the same joke about Jon Snow](http://www.businessinsider.in/Game-of-Thrones-fans-are-all-making-the-same-joke-about-Jon-Snow/articleshow/59949097.cms)

But it doesn't suit the character of Jon Snow. Jon Snow never tricked anyone like this before.

We already know the White Walkers were made by the Children of Forest to beat the First Men by use of the dragonglass dagger. So why is it impossible to think that the Children of Forest living near a place where they have this much dragonglass made these paintings?

Comment: Oh, wow!  I didn't even know that everyone else was thinking the same thing!  Hmmmmm...